# In Evan’s history class, 10 out of 100 key terms will be randomly selected to appear on the final exam ...

Tags: probability

In Evan’s history class, 10 out of 100 key terms will be randomly selected to appear on the final exam; Evan must then choose 7 of those 10 to define. Since he knows the format of the exam in advance, Evan is trying to decide how many key terms he should study.

a) Suppose that Evan decides to study s terms, where s is an integer between 0 and 100. Let X be the number of key terms appearing on the exam that he has studied. What is the distribution of X? Give the name and parameters, in terms of s.

b) Using a calculator or a computer, calculate the probability that Evan knows at least 7 of the 10 key terms that appear on the exam, assuming that s = 75 key terms.

- For part A I got the distribution of X to be X~HGeom(s,100 - s,10) with PMF of $P(X=k)$=$\binom{s}{k}$$\binom{100-s}{10-k}$/$\binom{100}{10}$ but I am not sure if my work is correct.
- For part B I got X~HGeom(75,25,10) but I am also unsure if my work is correct and I am also having trouble calculating it using a calculator to get a numeric answer.
- Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for (a) is all well and fine. To get (b) we need to evaluate the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=7}^{10}\frac{\binom{75}k\binom{25}{10-k}}{\binom{100}{10}}$$
I like using [mpmath](http://mpmath.org) for calculations like this:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 100
S = nsum(lambda k: binomial(75, k) * binomial(25, 10 - k) / binomial(100, 10), [7, 10])
print(S)
```

We get a result of $0.785384\dots$